# Moderate and delete facebook comments via external application

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments, spam

I would like to integrate facebook comments on our web site (many articles, many authors).  By experience, these comments have to be moderated and I would like to achieve two things:

1. Apply own filtering techniques to identify spam and hold back publishing.
2. Have granular control about who can moderate (eg. authors on comments on their own article)

Can you please advise me on how to achieve this?

My knowledge so far: if I use the comments box, everything gets submitted to Facebook directly.  I would be able to access the comments via Graph API, but not to modify them programatically (eg. delete them in facebook?).

a) Is there a way to delete a comment via an API, when I have the comment id from Graph-API?

b) Alternatively, can comments be submitted indirectly (visitor enters a comment, moderator approves, comment is sent to FB)

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this question? I'm in the same place! Thanks.

Comment: @mrisher No I did not get an answer, but I as far as I know now deleting is possible via GraphAPI. This is currently sufficient for me and I I will implement some custom programming as soon as I find some time.

Comment: martin, did you ever get deleting implemented via the graphapi? If "yes", can you share? Thanks!